# Is there a LaTeX package for annotating text/code?

Tags: code, annotations, command-line

I would like to annotate one-line code (shell commands) in a LaTeX document.

For example, the command `du -ah --max-depth=1 . | sort -h`.

I like the style in which shell commands are annotated at explainshell.com.
See https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=du+-ah+--max-depth%3D1+.+%7C+sort+-h

[image]

**How do you do that in LaTeX?

Are there maybe even packages for that purpose that I have not found so far?**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There is no package that I would know of, but it is straightforward with TikZ.